# How to format the raw date formats when using Google Analytic Reports?

Tags: views, google-analytics, charts

I am using [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools), [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), and [Google Analytic Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) to create charts for an admin dashboard.

However the date format (Time Dimensions: ga:date) outputs the date in the YYYYMMDD format.

How can I change that to something like Oct 31?

**Note**: I have been asking around and apparently NO ONE knows how to do this. Here are some relevant URLs about it:

- [Date Format in Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/1900994), related to the [Views Dataviz with Google Charts API](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dataviz) module.
- [Google analytics with views and google chart tools](https://www.drupal.org/node/1900660), related to the [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) module.
- [Format time duration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122643) (not the exact same issue, pretty close).

Comment: If you really have been asking so much, can you post links to support requests in issue queues? I mean, *no one* is a pretty strong claim...

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1900994
https://drupal.org/node/1900660 and while not the exact same issue, pretty close... https://drupal.org/node/2122643

Answer (score 0):

Feature request [#1900994](https://www.drupal.org/node/1900994) (from early 2013), with title "**Date Format in Views**", seems to have been delivered (fixed) near the end of 2014 via [issue #2368159](https://www.drupal.org/node/2368159), with title "**Add support for datapoints types**". Refer to description of the issue for more details about it (the problem description, and the actual solution that got implemented).

[Issue #2368159](https://www.drupal.org/node/2368159) also resolved the issue about [Format time duration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122643), a typical variation of the question here.